# Links from ajax request are not requested via ajax

Tags: ajax, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a userscript that fires an ajax call via GM_xmlhttprequest to load a simple page with some text and links into a div named "debug". this works very well. now I want, that every link in the requested document is requested via gm_xmlhttprequest. I don't know why my function is not working

```
    $('.ajax, .ajaxn').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: "GET",
                url: href,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    },
                        onload: function(response) {
                                $('#debug').html('');
                                $('#debug').append(response.responseText).fadeIn(5000);
                                        }
            });
});
```

The links inside the response have the class ajaxn, and the firebug dom/html panel shows that the response is actually inserted into the #debug

any hints?

Comment: You say "the response is actually inserted into the #debug". Then what is not working?

Comment: I think that you remove all previous content with the call to `$('#debug').html('');`. Try some `console.log` to find out if all xmlHttpRequests are executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not clear, but assuming you want that `click` handler to fire, if a link is clicked in the `#debug` content  (versus auto-loading the links or ???)...

Then don't use the `.click()` method.  Use [jQuery's `.on()` method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=on)  this fires on current, *and any future*, nodes that match the selector.

The code becomes something like:

```
$(document).on ("click", ".ajax, .ajaxn", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault ();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        method:     "GET",
        url:        href,
        headers:    {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        onload:     function (response) {
            $('#debug').empty ();
            $('#debug').append (response.responseText).fadeIn (5000);
        }
    } );
} );
```

Also, don't use `$('#debug').html('');`   Use [`$('#debug').empty();`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=empty) instead.  This will be a smidge faster and the code is a little more self-documenting.

Comment: +1, though it would be slightly more efficient to use `$('#debug').on("click", ".ajax, .ajaxn", function...` so the listener only fires for clicks within the `debug` div.

Comment: @IanRoberts, yes it would be more efficient, except it isn't clear that *all* the `.ajax` or `.ajaxn` nodes were in the `#debug` element, so I played it safe.